# Code improvement

Tags: ruby

Here is my code sample, let me know if it can be further improved?

```
excludedb = if File.exist?(arg)
  IO.read(arg).split(',').map { |db_name| db_name.strip }.delete_if { |db_name| db_name == "" }
else
  ["master", "model", "sybsystemdb", "sybsystemprocs", "tempdb", "sybsecurity", "pubs2", "pubs3", "dbccdb", "sybmgmtdb"]
end
```

Comment: What's do you not like about it?

Comment: This should be on [codereview.stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a couple of tiny improvements.

You can replace

```
.map { |db_name| db_name.strip }
```

with

```
.map(&:strip)
```

And also you can use string array literal

```
%w{master model sybsystemdb}
```